# Run-time error '1004' Cannot use that command on overlapping selections

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have this code and when I start the macro I get the error: Run-time error '1004' Cannot use that command on overlapping selections

```
'
    Range("B:B,D:J").Select
    Range("D1").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft (THE ERROR IS HERE)
    Columns("A:C").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Saldobalanse RHB").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

I hope someone can help me. How can I fix this please?

Comment: I can produce this if there are merged cells. Are there any? Also, there is no need to select anything. `ActiveSheet.Paste` is a poor choice i.e. you are praying that the selection is the correct cell in the first row. It could be tolerated if you had just added and renamed the worksheet when it would paste into cell `A1`, but why chance it when you can do `Sheets("Saldobalanse RHB").Range("A1").PasteSpecial` or even better `Columns("A:C").Copy Sheets("Saldobalanse RHB").Range("A1")`, Are these sheets in the workbook containing this code? Please describe in more detail what you're trying to do

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your thoughts and feedback. This is what I want to do:
I have to compare some numbers in sheet A. Therefore I paste a balance in sheet Saldobalanse Input. I only need 3 of the columns from the balance, therefore I have created a macro to delete some rows and paste these rows into the sheet Saldobalanse RHB.

Comment: You should test the code I posted below. Make sure to change the `Sheet1` to `A` or whatever the name is. BTW, if you don't want to delete the columns, you could just use `sws.Range("A:A,C:C,K:K").Copy dws.Range("A1")` in the code.

Comment: Hi again! My macro is failing, because the report I am copying from is different depending on who takes it out (somehow). So when the code says to delete the range B:J, the columns have been displaced somehow and I end up deleting the wrong columns and then copying the wrong information. I have to change the range in the vba every time I take out the report. I realize the delete step in the macro is unessecary as you pointed out, Is there any way to make the macro copy only the first and last column, or maybe copy only the column with the name: "Account" and "Net value" wherever it is placed?

Comment: This is kind of out of the scope of the question. Why don't you ask a new one and explain in more detail what any of the codes does and what it should be doing? Adding screenshots of your data is most often very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

### Delete and Copy Columns

- If there are no merged cells, the following should work.
- By using `Option Explicit` you are forced to declare all variables.
- By using variables it becomes transparent what the code is doing.
- The operations of the code are happening in the workbook containing the code (`ThisWorkbook`). The code is copying from worksheet `Sheet1` to worksheet `Saldobalanse RHB`.
- You can have any workbook or worksheet active, but the code will always run on the correct workbook or worksheet.
- As you can see, there is no need to select anything.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteAndCopyColumns()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' adjust
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Saldobalanse RHB")

    sws.Range("B:B,D:J").Delete xlShiftToLeft
    sws.Columns("A:C").Copy dws.Range("A1") ' or another cell in the first row

End Sub
```